# Use 2 Strings to call Function X from Module Y

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, module

So I've been working on a Menu Handler for one of my text games so that making menus would take up less space on a player's hard drive, but after using a piece of code I found here on stackOverflow, I found that the code doesn't allow for inputting the module to import it from as a string. My basic goal is to be able to create menus from a single line of code. I have most of that working, except for the fact that I don't know how to go about calling a function from a method, either using one or two strings.

The code I found:

```
    function = globals().copy()
    function.update(locals())

    function.get(call)(*actionsList)
```

Currently, call is the function that I am to call and actions list is just a list of parameters. I don't know how safe or efficient this is, but I do know that using a string like "moduleX.functionY" does not actually call functionY from moduleX. Are there any ways to do this?

Full code (For reference):

```
    Menu Handler:

    import subprocess as sp
    import Menus


    def callMenu(Options, Instructions):
        tmp = sp.call('cls',shell=True) 

        for key, value in Options.iteritems():
            print key

        print ""
        print Instructions

        processMenu(Options, Instructions)


    def processMenu(Options, Instructions):
        actionsList = []
        menuInput = ""

        menuInput = raw_input("")

        results = processInput(Options, menuInput)

        if results[0]:
            for key, value in Options[results[1]].items():
                call = key
                actionsList = value

            function = globals().copy()
            function.update(locals())

            function.get(call)(*actionsList)
        else:
          callMenu(Options, Instructions)

    def processInput(Options, menuInput):
           processedOptions = 0
          optionsList = []

          answer = False

        for key, value in Options.items():
            optionsList.append(key)

        while processedOptions < len(Options):
            currentKey = optionsList[processedOptions]

            if str(menuInput.lower()) == currentKey.lower():
                answer = True
                break

            processedOptions += 1

         return [answer, currentKey]

    def DEBUG(DUMMY):
        tmp = sp.call('cls',shell=True) 
        print "%s selected" % DUMMY
        menuInput = raw_input("")
        Menus.MainMenu.MenuMain000()


    Main Menu:

          from Handlers import MenuHandler

    def MenuMain000():
        MenuHandler.callMenu({"New Game": {"DEBUG": ["New Game"]}, "Load Game": {"DEBUG": ["Load Game"]}}, "Pick something will ya")

    #def MenuMain100(DUMMY):
            #print "%s selected" % DUMMY
```

I wish to be able to use MenuMain001 instead of DUMMY by having the menu call instead be

```
    MenuHandler.callMenu({"New Game": {"MenuMain001": ["New Game"]}, "Load Game": {"MenuMain001": ["Load Game"]}}, "Pick something will ya")
```

Comment: Is that code supposed to do something with a menu?

Comment: It's a code snippet, I have everything I need to do a menu thing except for a way to call functions from outside modules, I thought it wasn't exactly necessary for the task at hand, which is just finding a way to call a function from a method using one or two strings.

Comment: Eww...wow...why would you do that instead of just `call(args)`?

Comment: Sorry if it's noobish but what's call()?

Comment: I have no idea. It's the function you're getting with `get()` for whatever reason instead of indices.

Comment: Well, how would I call a function using call? The thing above is just the simplest way I've found to call a function so far

Comment: Just type a pair of parentheses after the function name, like this: `func()`.

Comment: No, I need to use a string to call a function, as the called function will be different depending on the selected menu option.

Comment: Ew, that's bad, too. Why? Why can't the menu function just return a function? Post more code, specifically, the menu function.

Comment: I can return a function and it won't think it's a variable?

Comment: Functions *are* variables. The `def` statement just defines a new variable. Functions are special, though, because they have [`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) defined.

Comment: Can you post the function that makes the menu?

Comment: So, how would I go about calling the function using the above code?

Comment: The function that makes the menu is at the end, labeled MenuMain000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the function itself to `callMenu()` instead of its name as a string:

```
MenuHandler.callMenu({"New Game": {DEBUG: ["New Game"]}, "Load Game": {DEBUG: ["Load Game"]}}, "Pick something will ya")
```

Then, in `processMenu()`,call the function instead of doing all that stuff with `globals()`:

```
call(*actionsList)
```

Comment: Wow. I did not think that would be so easy. I mean, wow. I thought it was going to need some Python wizardry or something. Thanks, it worked like a charm!